Jest stopped working and gets infinite loop
I haven't changed anything just added some tests and functions in controller, and suddenly jest has stopped working.
Every file I run fails and I get this issue. for example

npx jest test/routes/user/auth/login

thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a hook.
Add a timeout value to this test to increase the timeout, if this is a long-running test. See https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout."

I tried to comment all the new files and functions but it also didnt help.
jest.config.js:
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/test/setup-tests.ts'],
};

package.json:
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev ./src/index.ts | pino-pretty --colorize",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "jest --runInBand"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fastify/cors": "^8.5.0",
    "@fastify/formbody": "^7.4.0",
    "@fastify/helmet": "^11.1.1",
    "@fastify/mongodb": "^8.0.0",
    "@fastify/passport": "^2.4.0",
    "@fastify/secure-session": "^7.1.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "env-schema": "^5.2.0",
    "fastify": "^4.25.2",
    "generate-password": "^1.7.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.0.4",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^4.0.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.8",
    "passport-apple": "^2.0.2",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
    "winston": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "@types/mongoose-unique-validator": "^1.0.7",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.8",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.8",
    "@types/passport-apple": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.14",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^6.0.2",
    "@types/winston": "^2.4.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.62.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^36.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^16.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "jest": "^29.6.1",
    "pino-pretty": "^10.3.1",
    "prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}

